# How to avoid Sorting in Union ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server

MY question is simple, How do you avoid the automatic sorting which the UNION ALL query does?

This is my query

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP1 FROM Final

    SELECT * INTO #TEMP2 FROM #TEMP1 WHERE MomentId = @MomentId

    SELECT * INTO #TEMP3 FROM #TEMP1 WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow

    SELECT * INTO #TEMP4 FROM (SELECT *FROM #TEMP3 UNION ALL SELECT *FROM #TEMP2) as tmp

    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #TEMP4
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I need the Union ALL to perform like a simple Concatenate, which it isn't! Appreciate your help in this.

Comment: If you want to avoid sorting corresponding to `UNION ALL`. You need to put something of your own. What sorting do you need?

Comment: Why do a UNION ALL, immediately followed by a DISTINCT on that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mistaken on which operation is actually causing the sort. Check the code below, UNION ALL will *not* cause a sort. You may be looking at the DISTINCT operation, which uses a sort (it sorts all items and the eliminates duplicates)

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    i int
)

CREATE TABLE #temp2
(
    i int
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 

INSERT INTO #Temp2
SELECT 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 6 

SELECT * INTO #TEMP3 
FROM (SELECT * FROM #Temp1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM #temp2) X
```

Comment: Wow! Sorry my bad. I did not think Distinct was sorting the table all the while... Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: +1 I've put your example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a6b8/4) for all to see.

Comment: My question then would be, how to avoid Sorting in DISTINCT?

Comment: You can't unfortunately, that's just how the operation works. It sorts them all and eliminates duplicates. You can just UNION the results, but then each of your tables will be sorted. At some point you'll need to have them sorted to get unique values.

Comment: @GarethD SQLFiddle now shows execution plans too?! That's amazing. Thanks!

Comment: You can assist the sort by adding indexes, but ultimately, as Mike has said, it is how the operation works, the most efficient way to perform the distinct operation is by sorting the records. I have found that often `DISTINCT` is just masking a problem, rather than being the solution to one.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` adds all the records where as `UNION` adds only new/distinct records.

Since you are using `UNION ALL` and using `DISTINCT` soon after, I think you are looking for `UNION`

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP4 FROM
    (
     SELECT * FROM #TEMP3 
     UNION  --JUST UNION 
     SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
    ) AnotherTemp
```

Or you can simplify it as

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP4 FROM
        SELECT DISTINCT * 
        FROM Final
        WHERE MomentId = @MomentId OR RowNum BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
```

Comment: Not exactly. In my case depending on the specific circumstance, the Union would yield either 4 or 5 rows. But I must return 5 rows. I want this to happen like so. If there are only 4 rows in the final table, get another row into the table and return, and if there are 5 rows, return the table as is. Using UNION did not yield the desired result. So I'm still looking for work arounds

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQL-Server, but you might get my idea

```
select *, 'A' tid, rownumber() tno from tableA
union all
select *, 'B', rownumber() from tableB
order by tid, tno;
```

This should get you all records of tableA in their specific order, followed by all records of tableB in their specific order.